# Confusing with the equation $(2.4)$ and $(2.5)$ of Landau and Lifshitz, Mechanics, Chapter 1, The principle of Least Action

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

I'm a 12th Grader and I'm interested in Lagrangian Mechanics and having a bit of knowledge about the Newtonian Mechanics. So, I found a book of *Landau and Lifshitz's Mechanics* and started reading from the very first chapter, but I've encountered some serious doubts here!

I'm just writing the symbol/variable meaning and conventions here first!

For instance, let's imagine a particle. $q$ is it's radius vector magnitude (it's scalar), $\dot q$ is the derivative of position vector or velocity (scalar), $t$ as time duration, $S$ as action.

So, $$S = \int \limits_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q, \dot q, t) dt.\tag{2.1}$$

Let variation of function be $\delta q(t)$, so now

$$\delta q(t_1) = \delta q (t_2) =0 \tag{2.3}$$

$$\Rightarrow \qquad\delta S = \int \limits_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q+ \delta q, \dot q + \delta \dot q, t)dt - \int \limits_{t_1}^{t_2} L (q, \dot q, t)dt = 0.\tag{2.3b}$$

So, after the next few lines, it changes to:

$$\delta S = \delta \int \limits_{t_1}^{t_2} L(q, \dot q, t)dt =0.\tag{2.4}$$

This is doubtful as $\delta$ isn't a number which can be multiplied both sides of equal sign both ways,

$$\int \left ( \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} \delta q + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q} \delta \dot q \right)dt = 0.\tag{2.4b}$$

From which multiverse the above thing in concluded even I can't understand after hours of thinking, please help me with these concepts.

---

Ref: https://archive.org/details/Mechanics_541/page/n11

Comment: I would suggest you read this book, and how it covers the same topic: Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences, 3e, (Mary Boas),  its a free PDF download

Comment: Think of $\delta$ as an operator. Operators can be applied to equalities to produce equalities.

Answer (score 1):

What I have understood is that you want to know why the $\delta$ can be applied on both sides of the equation. Inform me if I have misinterpreted.

$\delta$ expresses the change of a function by a small amount. What this means is that for every input the the function gives a different output, except at the end points from which one gets the relation 
$$ \delta q(t_1)=\delta q(t_2)= 0 $$
where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are the end points. If I define a new function
$$ \bar{q} = q + \epsilon \eta $$ 
Where $\eta $ is some arbitrary function of $t$ where $\eta(t_1)=\eta(t_2)=0$. The variation in $q$ is 
$$ \delta q = \eta \epsilon$$
Taking the derivative 
$$ \delta \dot{q} = \eta \epsilon$$
Now the change in Lagrangian is 
$$\delta L = \big(\partial_{q} L \big)\delta q+ \big(\partial_{\dot{q}} L \big)\delta \dot{q}$$ 
The same can also be achieved by taking derivative of Lagrangian w.r.t. $\epsilon$.
$$\frac{d}{d\epsilon}L = \big(\partial_{\bar{q}} L \big)\frac{d\bar{q}}{d\epsilon} + \big(\partial_{\dot{\bar{q}}} L \big)\frac{d \dot{\bar{q}}}{d\epsilon}$$ 
The end result in both cases will be the same. In this method the derivative of $S$ w.r.t. $\epsilon$ will be zero. Taking the derivative or using variational method is **effectively** the same. Both sides of an equation can be varied just like you take the derivative of the equation on both sides. (just an analogy, **do not misinterpret $\delta$ as derivative**).

If you want further proof of Euler Lagrange equation you can get it on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) or Physics SE.

Hint (if you want to do it on your own): add and subtract

$$ \delta q \frac{d}{dt} \big( \partial_{\dot{q}} L \big) $$

in the fifth equation given in the question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: “$\delta$ is an operation that finds the change in a function when it's parameters are changed.” This confuses the infinitesimal variation of a functional with the infinitesimal variation of a function. The calculus of variations is about varying the function $q(t)$ itself, so that it becomes a slightly different function of $t$ for every value of $t$.

Comment: @G.Smith Agreed. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @G.Smith changed my answer. Thanks pointing out the confusion.